# Update only div after loading file with data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, d3.js

I'm very beginer and im trying to make simple chart with exchange rates. User can add data through the interface (works well, so I skipped this part) and load the data file to create the charts. Two charts with the exchange rate (dollar and euro) are displayed on the screen at the same time, so when user upload  files with his own data, should be updated only one div, and not the entire page.

So right now data uploads without updating page, **BUT** I cant (dont know how) to update my div with chart after that. I've tried to do that with:

```js
$("#dollarChart").load("../graph.php #dollarChart");
```

but it doesn't work.

So... here is my code:

graph.php :

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Graphs</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/testCss.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"><h1>Сurrency rate chart</h1></div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <a href="index.php">Add data</a>
            <a href="graph.php">Сurrency rate charts</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content">

            <!-- Sorting data on exchange rates from files -->
            <?php
                include "php/dataSort.php";
                dataSort("dollar.txt");
                dataSort("euro.txt");
            ?>

            <!-- Path to the files with the exchange rate-->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                let dollarFileName = "dollar.txt";
                let euroFileName = "euro.txt";
            </script>

            <!-- Block for displaying the dollar rate chart-->
            <div class = block1 id="dollarChart">
                <h2>Dollar rate chart</h2>
            </div>

            <!-- Load a script that draws a graph of the dollar rate -->
            <script src="script/dollarGraph.js">
            </script>

            <!-- Block for displaying the euro rate chart-->
            <div class = block2 id="euroChart">
                <h2>Euro rate chart</h2>
            </div>

            <!-- Load a script that draws a graph of the euro rate -->
            <script src="script/euroGraph.js">
            </script>


            <!-- Form to upload a file with data of the dollar exchange rate -->
            <br><form target="hiddenframe" action="php/dButton.php" name="uploadDollarFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dollarForm">
                Your data: <br><br><input type="file" name="dollarFileName" size="10" /><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submitD" value="upload" />
            </form>

            <!-- Form to upload a file with data of the euro exchange rate -->
            <br><form target="hiddenframe" action="php/eButton.php" name="uploadEuroFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="euroForm">
                Your data: <br><br><input type="file" name="euroFileName" size="10" /><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submitE" value="upload" />
            </form>

            <iframe id="hiddenframe" name="hiddenframe" style="width:0px; height:0px; border:0px"></iframe>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

dButton.php (after click this button on graph.php)

```js
<?php
    include 'dataSort.php'; //Sorts data in files, works fine
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["dollarFileName"]["tmp_name"]))        
    {
        $data = file($_FILES["dollarFileName"]["tmp_name"]);        //Write data from the uploaded file to an array
        file_put_contents("../loadDollarFile.txt", implode("\n", $data));       //Writing data to a file
        dataSort("../loadDollarFile.txt");      //Sorting data
        $dollarFileName = "../loadDollarFile.txt";
    }
?>

<script> dollarFileName = "<?php echo ($dollarFileName); ?>" </script>      <!-- Pass the file path to the JS variable -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<script src="../script/dollarGraph.js">     //Call the script to build the chart
    $("#dollarChart").load("../graph.php #dollarChart");        //Update the div with ID = 'dollarChart' !!! THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK
</script>
```

dollarGraph.js

```js
let dMargin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    dWidth = 800 - dMargin.left - dMargin.right,
    dHeight = 400 - dMargin.top - dMargin.bottom;

let svg1 = d3.select("#dollarChart")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", dWidth + dMargin.left + dMargin.right)
    .attr("height", dHeight + dMargin.top + dMargin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + dMargin.left + "," + dMargin.top + ")");


  function row(d){
    return { date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date), value : d.value }
}
  let dsv = d3.dsvFormat(";");
  d3.request(dollarFileName)
  .mimeType("text/plain")
  .response(function(data) { return dsv.parse(data.response, row)})
  .get(function(data) {
      // use data.
    let dateCurrent = Date.now()
    data = data.filter(function (d){return d.date >= dateCurrent - 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000})

    // X axis
    let now = new Date();
    let x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([now - (365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000), d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.date; })])   //We mark the X axis from "A year ago" to "Chronologically last date in the file"
      .range([ 0, dWidth ]);
    svg1.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + dHeight + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Y axis
    let y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([d3.min(data, function (d) { return +d.value; })-2, d3.max(data, function (d) { return +d.value; })])   //We mark the Y axis from "2 less than the minimum course value" to "Maximum course value"
      .range([ dHeight, 0 ]);
    svg1.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    svg1.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.date) })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.value) })
      )
      console.log(data);
  })
```

Data saved in .txt files (it should be so). this is how they looks:

```js
date;value
2021-01-01;30
2020-12-31;31.13
2020-12-31;30
2020-12-31;26.22
2020-12-15;32.33
2020-12-15;22.33
2020-12-12;36.33
```

And here is my folder structure:

```js
php
  |_dataSort.php
  |_dButton.php
  |_eButton.php

script
  |_dollarGraph.js
  |_euroGraph.js

style
  |_style.css
  |_testCss.css

dollar.txt
euro.txt
graph.php
index.php
loadDollarFile.txt
loadEuroFile.txt
```

I get that it's not the best code ever, but still... I just wanna make it work :)
There is no errors in my browser, so I think that I made a mistake in the path to something or didn't call some function.

I count on your help and I will be very grateful for it!